# Link on a tree action open a report with results by passed parameter

Tags: tree, report, oracle-apex

I need to know how i can filter a report (classic/interactive) on the same page of my tree by clicking a tree node. 
An example of this can be found on this site:

http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=36648:34:1599336964673301::NO:::

I have tried this query to compose my tree:

```
select case when connect_by_isleaf = 1 then 0
            when level = 1             then 1
            else                           -1
       end as status, 
       level, 
       "NAME" as title, 
       null as icon, 
       "ID" as value, 
       null as tooltip, 
       decode(level, 1, 'f?p=&APP_ID.:106:'||:APP_SESSION||'::::P106_MAQ_ID:'||ID, 
                     2, 'f?p=&APP_ID.:106:'||:APP_SESSION||'::::::::P106_MAQ_ID:'||(ID-1000), 
                     3, 'f?p=&APP_ID.:104:'||:APP_SESSION||'::::P106_MAQ_ID:'||(ID-10000), 
                     4, 'f?p=&APP_ID.:105:'||:APP_SESSION||'::::P106_MAQ_ID:'||(ID-100000)
             ) as link 
from "#OWNER#"."V_TREE1"
start with "PID" is null
connect by prior "ID" = "PID"
order siblings by "NAME"
```

But the parameter passed doesn't change the report the one row with ID passed. I need to obtain the same results shown on the website posted above.

I obtained success on action to redirect to another page which is a Form, which is accessed to edit through a Report, but not to show. And i want to show on the same page.

Below is the query i used to redirect:

```
select case when connect_by_isleaf = 1 then 0
            when level = 1             then 1
            else                           -1
       end as status, 
       level, 
       "NAME" as title, 
       null as icon, 
       "ID" as value, 
       null as tooltip, 
       decode(level, 1, 'f?p=&APP_ID.:102:'||:APP_SESSION||'::::P102_MAQ_ID:'||ID, 
                     2, 'f?p=&APP_ID.:103:'||:APP_SESSION||'::::P103_SRV_ID:'||(ID-1000), 
                     3, 'f?p=&APP_ID.:104:'||:APP_SESSION||'::::P104_INS_ID:'||(ID-10000), 
                     4, 'f?p=&APP_ID.:105:'||:APP_SESSION||'::::P105_SIS_ID:'||(ID-100000)
             ) as link 
from "#OWNER#"."V_TREE1"
start with "PID" is null
connect by prior "ID" = "PID"
order siblings by "NAME"
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

- What is your page with the tree? Page 106?
- Do you have an item there?
- Does that page have a report?
- What is the query used for that report?

Most probably you have not altered your report query. Let's assume your tree/report page is 106, and you want to filter your result to `P106_MAQ_ID`.
You will need to include this in your where-clause:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE MAQ_ID = :P106_MAQ_ID;
```

There is also an error in your posted query. Your decode for level 2 contains too many colons for a valid apex url (`2, 'f?p=&APP_ID.:106:'||:APP_SESSION||'::::::::P106_MAQ_ID:'||(ID-1000),)`